# Liferay DXP -- Navigation Section is missing for site in the control panel

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

After installing the latest fix pack (number 29) when I started liferay back up. When I opened the left menu, the navigation section was missing from the site config. Liferay is complaining that com.liferay.layouts.admin.web.GroupPagePortlet is not deployed. Is there anyway to fix this? I think it is a DB problem because when I restarted Liferay and pointed to a blank DB the nav section was back. I can't figure out what is different.

Comment: As you have the supported version: why don't you just open a ticket?

Comment: ...and in addition to the suggestion of opening a ticket: Please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/is-cross-posting-wrong-to-an-external-site and act accordingly